# Android xml graphical layout is not working for eclipse IDE

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I am getting a "No XML content. Please add a root view or layout to your document" When the code part of the xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As always help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of ADT you are using?

Comment: it work right in my eclipse, so suggestion clean your project and rebuild.

Comment: Have you cleaned your project?

Comment: No luck unfortunately, thanks for suggesting, yes Android Addict just did that.

Comment: Have you tried editing the text in another text editor? Maybe some un-welcome character snuck in?

Comment: can you post your activity class code to find where is problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, oddly enough it worked today, so for any googlers: wait a day I guess. Thanks everyone for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy+paste this code from somewhere? Maybe there's a non-printable character in there that the XML processor is encountering and throwing it for a loop. As a test, try creating a new layout file and manually typing in the contents from above. If that works, you can throw away the file above and use the new one.

Comment: This is just the base for no projects main.xml. My more complex ones give the same error.